# Pivot table to turn rows into columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I currently run the query

```
SELECT [PriceAttributeID]
  ,[PriceID]
  ,[AttributeID]
  ,[PriceAttributeComparator]
  ,[PriceAttributeMin]
  ,[PriceAttributeMax]
FROM [PriceAttribute]
```

Which gives the output

```
1   2   1   1   S   NULL
2   3   1   1   M   NULL
3   4   1   1   L   NULL
4   5   1   1   L   NULL
5   5   2   1   Black   NULL
```

I would like to get the output (where `_Comp`, `_Min` and `_Max` relate to `PriceAttributeComparator`, `PriceAttributeMin` and `PriceAttributeMax`)

```
PriceID    1_Comp    1_Min    1_Max    2_Comp    2_Min    2_Max
      2         1        S     NULL      NULL     NULL     NULL
      3         1        M     NULL      NULL     NULL     NULL
      4         1        L     NULL      NULL     NULL     NULL
      5         1        L     NULL         1    Black     NULL
```

The same query would also be expected to have `1_` and `2_` prefixes as `4_`, `5_`, `19_` and `32_` or any other indeterminate number of ID's based on what is in the table at the time.

I have attempted a PIVOT table, but i am new to them and haven't the first clue on how to create what it is i am looking to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the problem you are probably having with the PIVOT function is due to the fact you have multiple columns that you want to apply the function to.  If you want to use the PIVOT function, then I would suggest first unpivoting the columns `PriceAttributeComparator`, `PriceAttributeMin` and `PriceAttributeMax`.  When you unpivot the data you will no longer have multiple columns, you will have multiple rows, then you can apply the pivot to all of the appropriate values.

You did not specify what version of SQL Server you are using but you can use CROSS APPLY with a UNION ALL to unpivot the columns:

```
select priceid, 
  col = cast(attributeid as varchar(10))+'_'+ col, 
  value
from 
(
  select PriceID, 
    AttributeID, 
    comp = cast(PriceAttributeComparator as varchar(10)),
    [min] = cast(PriceAttributeMin as varchar(10)), 
    [max] = cast(PriceAttributeMax as varchar(10))
  from PriceAttribute
) d
cross apply
(
  select 'comp', comp union all
  select 'min', [min] union all
  select 'max', [max] 
) c (col, value)
```

See [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a3a23/9). This process will convert your data into the following format:

```
| PRICEID |    COL |  VALUE |
-----------------------------
|       2 | 1_comp |      1 |
|       2 |  1_min |      S |
|       2 |  1_max | (null) |
|       3 | 1_comp |      1 |
|       3 |  1_min |      M |
|       3 |  1_max | (null) |
```

Once the data is in multiple rows, then you can apply the PIVOT function to the values in `col`:

```
select priceid,
  [1_comp], [1_min], [1_max], [2_comp], [2_min], [2_max]
from
(
  select priceid, 
    col = cast(attributeid as varchar(10))+'_'+ col, 
    value
  from 
  (
    select PriceID, 
      AttributeID, 
      comp = cast(PriceAttributeComparator as varchar(10)),
      [min] = cast(PriceAttributeMin as varchar(10)), 
      [max] = cast(PriceAttributeMax as varchar(10))
    from PriceAttribute
  ) d
  cross apply
  (
    select 'comp', comp union all
    select 'min', [min] union all
    select 'max', [max] 
  ) c (col, value)
) src
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for col in ([1_comp], [1_min], [1_max], [2_comp], [2_min], [2_max])
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a3a23/10).

The above versions work great if you have a known number of values but if the values are unknown, then you will need to use dynamic SQL to get the result:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(cast(attributeid as varchar(10))+'_'+ col) 
                    from
                    (
                      select distinct attributeid
                      from priceattribute
                    ) d
                    cross apply
                    (
                      select 'comp', 1 union all
                      select 'min', 2 union all
                      select 'max', 3 
                    ) c (col, so)
                    group by attributeid, col, so
                    order by attributeid, so
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT priceid, ' + @cols + ' 
            from 
            (
                select priceid, 
                  col = cast(attributeid as varchar(10))+''_''+ col, 
                  value
                from 
                (
                  select PriceID, 
                    AttributeID, 
                    comp = cast(PriceAttributeComparator as varchar(10)),
                    [min] = cast(PriceAttributeMin as varchar(10)), 
                    [max] = cast(PriceAttributeMax as varchar(10))
                  from PriceAttribute
                ) d
                cross apply
                (
                  select ''comp'', comp union all
                  select ''min'', [min] union all
                  select ''max'', [max] 
                ) c (col, value)
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(value)
                for col in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute sp_executesql @query;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a3a23/11).  These solutions will give a result:

```
| PRICEID | 1_COMP | 1_MIN |  1_MAX | 2_COMP |  2_MIN |  2_MAX |
----------------------------------------------------------------
|       2 |      1 |     S | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) |
|       3 |      1 |     M | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) |
|       4 |      1 |     L | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) |
|       5 |      1 |     L | (null) |      1 |  Black | (null) |
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be simplest to do this using conditional aggregation rather than pivot:

```
SELECT PriceID,
       max(case when AttributeID = 1 then PriceAttributeComparator end) as comp_1,
       max(case when AttributeID = 1 then PriceAttributeMin end) as min_1,
       max(case when AttributeID = 1 then PriceAttributeMax end) as max_1,
       max(case when AttributeID = 2 then PriceAttributeComparator end) as comp_2,
       max(case when AttributeID = 2 then PriceAttributeMin end) as min_2,
       max(case when AttributeID = 2 then PriceAttributeMax end) as max_2
FROM PriceAttribute pa
group by PriceId;
```

Comment: This is what i currently have and am looking to turn into a pivot, because the AttributeID's and the number of attribute id's that are available at any given time vary

Comment: @bizzehdee . . . The pivot doesn't help with that.  You have to list the attributes for pivoting in a list.  You might need a dynamic SQL solution.